# creating sticky nav bar

Tags: html, css

Being new to HTML and CSS i was trying to create a Sticky Navigation Bar and it seems like i did not code it right. I have posted my code below, please do help me out with the issue.
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            html,
            body {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
            }
            nav{
              min-height: 40px;
              height: 55px;
              background-color: #67518e;
              width: 100%;
            }
            div{
              padding-top: 30px;
              padding-bottom: 30px;
              border-top: 1px solid green;
              border-bottom: 1px solid green;
              background-color: yellow;
              width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
        </nav>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve that this isnt doing?

Comment: add `position:fixed;` for `nav`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `position: fixed` on you `nav` with top and left values..

```
top:0;
left:0;
position:fixed;
```

and your `div` need to have `margin-top` equal to `nav`-height, otherwise it will just overlay each togther;

```
margin-top:55px;
```

Here is a fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/h9u1fe4v/